# Working with a GSM Modem

Tags: modem, gsm

I was keen on knowing how can I receive calls on a web server using a GSM Modem?

I'm a newbie to it, wanted to explore the space.

Would be glad if someone can help me on this, probably with some tutorial links etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to connect the modem to your server and then have some sort of background program/process that reads/writes to it.  You create a serial connection and the read/write AT commands to it.